# syntax error instantiating an object in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I'm using the library STPrivilegedTask library, source found at http://www.sveinbjorn.org/STPrivilegedTask to run the NSTask with sudo permissions.

This is the code I'm using to instantiate an STPrivilegedTask object but I'm getting syntax error:

`STPrivilegedTask *task2 = [[STPrivilegedTask alloc] initWithLaunchPath: launchPath: arguments];`

I'm getting "Receiver type STPrivilegedTask for instance method does not declare a method..." error. Is the above syntax valid?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an expert in objective-C, but if I'm not wrong, you should call it like that:

```
STPrivilegedTask *task2 = [[STPrivilegedTask alloc] initWithLaunchPath: launchPath
arguments:arguments];
```

(Assuming `arguments` in your method is your NSArray) Since the declaration of the method is:

```
- (id)initWithLaunchPath: (NSString *)path arguments:  (NSArray *)args;
                                           ^^^ Part of the method signature
```

And not

```
- (id)initWithLaunchPath: (NSString *)path :  (NSArray *)args;
```

This is an example from the `.m` file in the link you added:

```
STPrivilegedTask *task = [[[STPrivilegedTask alloc] initWithLaunchPath: path arguments: args] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's not the correct name for that method at all.

That method's selector is `initWithLaunchPath:arguments:`. When you're calling a method, you insert the arguments after the colons in the selector. So assuming that the launch path is stored in a variable called `path` and the arguments are stored in a variable called `programArguments`, you would call the method like this:

```
[[STPrivilegedTask alloc] initWithLaunchPath:path arguments:programArguments];
```